# Calling service method in a Vue template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have

```
<template>
  <button @click="doSomething">...</button>
</template>

<script>
import ApiService from '../service/api.service';
export default {
  setup() {
      function doSomething() {
        ApiService.doSomething();
      }
      return {
        doSomething
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

If I make it shorter (like I'm used in Angular):

```
<template>
  <button @click="ApiService.doSomething">...</button>
</template>

<script>
import ApiService from '../service/api.service';
</script>
```

It doesn't work, throws a runtime error.
(It doesn't work even if I try as function call:
@click="ApiService.doSomething()"

Can you help, how to save time/code and directly call **ApiService.doSomething** just in a template?

---

P.S.
they asked me to post ApiService also so here it is:
api.service.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import router from '@/router';

const ApiService = {

    init(baseURL) {
        axios.defaults.baseURL = baseURL;
    },

    //...

    doSomething() {
        router.push({ path: '/goSomewhere' });
    },

}

export default ApiService
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work because you need to pass it through the `setup` function to be available in the template.

you can do this though:

```html
<template>
  <button @click="ApiService.doSomething">...</button>
</template>

<script>
import ApiService from '../service/api.service';
export default {
  setup() {
      return { ApiService }
  }
}
</script>
```

Alternatively, you may also use the `setup` attribute for script, which does some hoisting magic for you. ([rfc link](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/sfc-improvements/active-rfcs/0000-sfc-script-setup.md#basic-example))

```html
<template>
  <button @click="ApiService.doSomething">...</button>
</template>

<script setup>
import ApiService from '../service/api.service';
export ApiService;
</script>
```

Comment: But for the second solution, I get compiler error "'ApiService' is defined but never used"

Comment: my bad, I missed the export

Comment: Works, but I had to put ApiService in brackets: export {ApiService}  otherwise it threw error: Unexpected token, expected "{"

Comment: This last solution throws an error: This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: 'exportDefaultFrom'

Comment: The previous version of your second solution was fine, if I wrap ApiService in brackets.

Comment: interesting.  according to https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/sfc-improvements/active-rfcs/0000-sfc-script-setup.md#exposing-components it should have been working. Reverted it back

Comment: But it doesn't work this way; second line should be: export {ApiService}  . I know it's weird and this compiler drives me crazy

Comment: maybe the difference is in the `{___ as ___}` ‍♂️. One of the reasons I prefer more explicit definitions.

Comment: you could also `export {...ApiService}` if you want all the functions available without the "namespace"

Comment: Nope. This throws: "Parsing error: Unexpected token"

Answer (score 2):

You could spread that service functions in the methods option `methods:{...ApiService }` :

```
<template>
  <button @click="doSomething">...</button>
</template>

<script>
import  ApiService from '../service/api.service';
export default {
methods:{
  ...ApiService
}
}
</script>
```

**api.service.js**

```
const ApiService = {
  doSomething() {
    console.log("doing something");
  },

  doSomething2() {
    console.log("doing something 2");
  },

  doSomething3() {
    console.log("doing something 3");
  }
};

export default ApiService;
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-rgb-hszmr?file=/src/Hello.vue)**

Comment: As Daniel proved in his first solution, it is possible.

Comment: Ok, what about my suggestion?

Comment: I don't want to use like 20 methods importing one by one... (import { doSomething, doSomething2, doSomething3 } )... I need ApiService methods, that's why it's a service.

Comment: what about spread that service functions in the methods option `methods:{...ApiService }`

Comment: What if I need "doSomething" in my current view and I also use doSomething from service? But please update the answer with the complete code so I can try it, because your initial solution anyway throws a runtime error in runtime-core.esm-bundler: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Comment: Thanks, but then I need to modify my whole ApiService. I have a POJO const ApiService = {...}, and then at the end: export default ApiService

Comment: please share a snippet from your ApiService object that demonstrates its structure

Comment: it's also valid with your object syntax `import ApiService from '../service/api.service';` and `methods:{...ApiService}` please check this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-rgb-hszmr?file=/src/Hello.vue)

Comment: Thank you, it works so I'll give your comment above this another upvote. However, your answer doesn't gets upvote because of several reasons: I wanted Vue3 solution with setup(). Second, I can't use method "doSomething" locally in this way because of conflict with the same name, I specifically wanted to have a call "ApiService.doSomething" as I mentioned in my question. Third, Daniel solution was simpler and right on what I wanted and expected from Vue3. Thanks anyway.

Comment: you're welcome, i tried to provide a shorter code as you asked, i suggested the spreading in order to avoid calling `AppService.methodName` every time, if you prefer the composition api, you could do `setup(){ return{...ApiService}}` then `@click="doSomething"`

Comment: my approach is the same as `mapActions` of vuex when you spread store actions  in methods option

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding parentheses to the function call?

```
<template>
  <button @click="ApiService.doSomething()">...</button>
</template>

<script>
import ApiService from '../service/api.service';
</script>
```

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. However, I will modify the question